# Spring MVC Ajax App

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm beginner in **Spring MVC** and trying to build an APP with only **ajax** redirects, but I don't know how to use ajax in **Spring MVC**.

I searching on Google but I don't find nothing to beginners in **Spring MVC**.

Someone can help me with some tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can refer to this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/